# Hibernate dependencies, Cannot find scanner class

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jboss, persistence, pom.xml

In my pom.xml i have added the following dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Because before, in my log console the same error appeared, `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate4.HibernateAnnotationScanner` , then i added the hibernate.anotations dependency but the error persists, need i another dependencies to make it start?

This problem began when i added the persistence.xml to my project.
I am using a Jboss EAP 6.1 server.

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED:

I needed to install a newer version of that dependency, add the core dependency and change the entitymanager dependency version to the same as core.